# MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled while trying to render angular2 using express

Tags: html, node.js, angular, express

I'm trying to use Angular2 and NodeJS, express in my new project and running into an issue. Ive used cli to ng build the Angular2 project and have the dist folder generated.

Now when I try to point this folder using express, I can see only the "Hello world" html in the index.html. In the networks tab on dev tools on chrome, I can see the .js files getting called with 200OK but however they seem to return the index.html in response. And on browser console, I see errors on the js files as below.

Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost:8080/inline.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Same error for rest of the js files.

I've tried: 
    1. CORS to allow *
    2. Content-type: application/javascript on before res.sendFile(__dist+'index.html');
    3. ng serve seem to work file from localhost:4200 though. But I need express to render the page.

Not sure how to solve the issue. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: 1. The error message says nothing about CORS. 2. Why would telling the browser that your `index.html` file was JavaScript help?

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
app.use(express.static('your angular dist folder here'))
```

For more info about serving static files, you can get [here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).